# what does '-q' means in pip install -q <package name>?

Tags: python, pip

In the below example, I am trying to install gradio package but I have seen -q flag is used in some tutorials to install packages.What does '-q' flag means in pip install -q ?

pip install **-q** gradio

Comment: Did you try using `pip help install` and read what it says about `-q`? **Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).**

Comment: `-q` flag means less output. You should try reading `pip help install` or `man pip`.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#quiet

Comment: Check out all the available options with the detailed descriptions in the official documentation: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `pip3 --help` gives you this:

```
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be
                              used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING,
                              ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
```

So the `-q` option reduces the output produced by pip. It does not affect the installation process. It is a general option.